# How to use Jetty quickstart with embedded Jetty?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/operations-guide/index.html#og-quickstart

Is it possible to use Jetty Quickstart with embedded Jetty. We do not have a `web.xml`.

Our goal is to decrease startup times by eliminating Jetty's classpath scanning. If we cannot get Quickstart to work,

1. is it possible to retrieve everything that Jetty registered during classpath scanning, and
2. can we disable Jetty's classpath scanning and instead manually specify classes?

```java
final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();

final ResourceFactory resourceFactory = ResourceFactory.of(context);

context.setDisplayName("PORTAL");
context.setContextPath("/");

final Resource webRootResource = findWebRoot(resourceFactory);

context.setBaseResource(webRootResource);

context.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*");
context.setConfigurationDiscovered(true);
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
        new AnnotationConfiguration(),
        new WebAppConfiguration(),
        new WebInfConfiguration(),
        new WebXmlConfiguration(),
        new MetaInfConfiguration(),
        new FragmentConfiguration(),
        new EnvConfiguration(),
        new PlusConfiguration(),
        new JettyWebXmlConfiguration(),
        new JakartaWebSocketConfiguration()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Webapps (either `*.war` files, or exploded directories) are the only thing in Jetty that have the auto-discovery / bytecode scanning features.

The quickstart mechanism is for webapps.

It works by having the webapp initialization look for a `WEB-INF/quickstart-web.xml` during the startup of the `WebAppContext`.

See [Enable Jandex index for Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249263/enable-jandex-index-for-Jetty) for how to do generate that `WEB-INF/quickstart-web.xml` in an embedded mode application.

If you don't need a war file, use a `ServletContextHandler` and just add all of the servlets / filters / listeners your application needs against that `ServletContextHandler`.  There will be no auto discovery performed.

Comment: Thank you. How can I list everything that Jetty found during auto-discovery, so I know what to list? And then how do I disable auto-discovery?

Comment: Either just run the quickstart and look at the resulting XML.  or use the `WebAppContext.dump()` after it has started.

Comment: I tried adding the `QuickStartConfiguration` but there is no output.

Comment: Just adding `QuickStartConfiguration` isn't enough.  Look at the linked code at the other stackoverflow answer, it shows what you need to do to generate the quickstart.

Comment: I also set `MODE`. But I do not have a `web.xml`. Also, `WebAppContext.dump()` seems to dump more than what was registered during scanning. Is there a way to get all of the classes annotated with https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-12/operations-guide/index.html#og-annotations that were scanned.